# Rails 4 Filter Boolean True

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a page that I would like to link to and filter down to all records where the boolean attribute is true.

```
<div class="filter btn btn-default btn-directory active"><%= link_to "Accepting", people_path(:filter_by => :search == true ), {:method => :get} %></div>
```

This does not drop any errors, but it does not fetch any results either.

From the controller:

```
def index
        @people = Person.all

        if params[:filter_by]
            @people = Person.where(:position => params[:filter_by])
        else
            @people = Person.all
        end
    end
```

Comment: This syntax `people_path(:filter_by => :search == true )` is just adding `?filer_by=false` to your request params -- probably not what you expect. Can you include more details on your view/controller code and what you're trying to do? I assume you're trying to link to a list of all people filtered by some params?

Comment: I have added in the controller text for the view. I can see now, that I forgot about the filter_by text in the controller. Can I set up the filer_by IF statement with a `elsif` for the `search` attribute? 

And yes, you are correct, I am trying to filter the controller's index page to list just people where the `search == true`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to fetch all values where `person.search == true`:

Send a param in your `people_path` as follows:

```
link_to "Accepting", people_path(filter_by: true)
```

Then, in `PeopleController#index`:

```
def index
  Person.where("search = ?", params[:filter_by] == "true")
end
```

Comment: This makes sense, but with the IF statement in the  `def index`, it still does not return anything. This is how I dropped it in, am I missing something?

`if params[:filter_by]
      @people = Person.where(:position => params[:filter_by])
     elsif 
      @people = Person.where("search = ?", params[:filter_by] == "true")
    else
      @people = Person.all
    end`

Comment: What is the value of `params[:filter_by]` supposed to be in your example?

Comment: It is filtering the index by position of each peoson (i.e. staff, student, faculty), this new filter is supposed to now filter by where the faculty is accepting new students.